# Converting $C_1e^{i\omega t} + C_2 e^{-i\omega t} $ to $A\cos(\omega t +\phi) $

Tags: calculus

It seems intuitive to be able to replace:
$$C_1e^{i\omega t} + C_2 e^{-i\omega t} $$

by:
$$ A\cos(\omega t +\phi) $$

And not lose any "information". But I was wondering if there is any algebraic manipulation I can do to show that it is indeed the case.

Comment: So I guess you're referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula ? Is there anything else that you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this won't work for  general $C_1$ and $C_2$. Supposing $C_1$ and $C_2$ are real (the following argument can also be extended - below - to complex $C_1$ and $C_2$) you have the identity
$$C_1e^{i\omega t} + C_2 e^{-i\omega t} = \sqrt{C_1 \cdot C_2} (e^{\phi + i\omega t} + e^{- \phi -i\omega t} )
$$
where $\phi = \frac12 (\log C_1 - \log C_2)$

So you don't receive a $\cos$-function with a real phase shift.

For complex $C_1$ and $C_2$, write w.l.o.g. $C_1 = |C_1|e^{i \alpha_1}$ and  $C_2 = |C_2|e^{i \alpha_2}$. Then the above identity generalizes to
$$C_1e^{i\omega t} + C_2 e^{-i\omega t} = e^{i \frac12 (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)}\sqrt{|C_1| \cdot |C_2|} (e^{\phi + i(\omega t + \gamma)} + e^{- \phi -i(\omega t + \gamma)} )
$$
where $\phi = \frac12 (\log |C_1| - \log |C_2|)$ and $\gamma = \frac12 (\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)$. Hence $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ lead to a real phase shift of $\omega t$ which is what OP was intending.

In general,  we identify $A = e^{i \frac12 (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)}\sqrt{|C_1| \cdot |C_2|} $ and we see that it is $\phi$ which prevents us from writing the desired $\cos$-function with real phase shift, which, in turn, is possible only if $\phi=0$, i.e. iff $|C_1|=|C_2|$.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible for complex $A$ iff $|C_1|=|C_2|$, and is possible for real $A$ iff $C_2=\overline{C_1}$.

(I assume $\phi$ is restricted to real values, too.)

The "only if"s are because if we rewrite $A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$ in terms of complex exponentials, the coefficients $C_1=\frac{1}{2}Ae^{i\phi}$ and $C_2=\frac{1}{2}Ae^{-i\phi}$ have the same size, and indeed if $A$ is real then the coefficients $C_1$ and $C_2$ must be complex conjugates.

Conversely, if $|C_1|=|C_2|$ then $C_1=Ce^{i(\theta+\phi)}$ and $C_2=Ce^{i(\theta-\phi)}$ for some angles $\theta,\phi$ and

$$ C_1e^{i\omega t}+C_2e^{-i\omega t}= Ce^{i\theta}(e^{i(\omega t+\phi)}+e^{-i(\omega t+\phi)})=A\cos(\omega t+\phi) \tag{$\ast$} $$

where $A=2Ce^{i\theta}$. If $C_2=\overline{C_1}$ then $\phi=0$ and $A$ is real of course.

If you want to allow complex values for $\phi$ then you can write $C_1=e^{\theta+i\phi}$ and $C_2=e^{\theta-i\phi}$ for complex values of $\theta$ and $\phi$ and do the same algebraic manipulation as $(\ast)$.